# Finding a negative vector of a (very large) self adjoint matrix.

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have a self adjoint (finite) square matrix $A$ and I know that at least one of its eigenvalues is negative. Is there a way, avoiding iterative methods, to compute some $x$ such that
$$
\langle Ax,x\rangle<0.
$$
Note that I don't care whether $x$ is an eigenvector - I only care that the above inner product is negative. The eigenvalue condition simply ensures such an $x$ exists.

Comment: How much time can you spend? $O (n^3) $? Or less?

Comment: I am not bothered by complexity (in fact my matrix tends to be sparse). The reason I don't want iterative algorithms is that I want a guarantee of stability and finite computation time.

Comment: My concern is about why you do not choose to just find a negative eigenvector. Is it to save time or what?

Comment: I was thinking it could be a halting criteria - I can stop when an $x$ is found. The application I am interested in only requires this weaker form so I thought it might be easier. If there is a nice way to find the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue then even better!

Comment: Sure: apply your favorite constrained minimization algorithm to $f(x)=\langle x,Ax \rangle$ subject to $\| x \|=1$. Stop when the objective function becomes negative. It's not clear to me that this can truly be done "non-iteratively" but I doubt it would take even $d$ steps where $d$ is the dimension.

Comment: Why is non iterative difficult? I understand this for the full eigenvalue decomposition but was hoping that it was easier for largest or smallest.

Comment: What about a LDLT decomposition? By Hamilton inertia theorem, the number of negative eigenvalues is equal to the number of negative entries of the diagonal matrix $D$, and $L^Tx=e_k$ is easily solvable.

Comment: Well, the optimization problem has $f(x)=x^T A x,\nabla f(x)=2 Ax,\nabla g(x)=2x$. So the projected gradient descent looks like $x_{k+1}=\frac{x_k-\alpha_k A x_k}{\| x_k - \alpha_k A x_k \|}$ where $\alpha_k$ is chosen according to your favorite line search algorithm. I started playing with this using a random $10 \times 10$ matrix and my examples converged to a "negative vector" in your sense in just one step (in this case with an equal number of positive and negative eigenvalues). Maybe give this a shot before totally ruling it out?

Comment: @LutzL Is it straightforward to convert from an LU (obtainable by a direct method) to a LDLT? (Sincere question.)

Comment: @Mathmo I cooked up a $9 \times 9$ example with just one negative eigenvalue. Unsurprisingly, the performance worsened; $\alpha=1$ gave bigger values of $f$, and even after running a line search I still had a positive value of $f$. Still, this seems like it has promise to me.

Comment: @Ian : Yes, $U=DL^T$, which means since $L$ is known that one just has to read $D$ off of the diagonal of $U$. Of course that is only valid without permutations. And there are cases where one needs $D$ to have some $\pmatrix{0&a\\a&0}$ diagonal blocks.

Comment: In that case I think LutzL's idea might be very useful if you want a non-iterative method. I think you can also immediately stop as soon as you see a negative pivot: if the first negative pivot is in the $k$th column then the solution to $L^T x = e_k$ will have zeros in the last $n-k$ entries. The only problem here is that this is a matrix method, not a black box method, so sparsity will likely not help you. A black box method can take advantage of sparsity.

Comment: Though I'm not sure that will work if it turned out that a permutation was required later on in the procedure.

Comment: @Mathmo Have you tried anything since this discussion in the comments began? I am curious to know whether we have answered your question.

Comment: This is brilliant. I'm just checking out how to compute $D$ and $L$ directly but this looks very hopeful.

Comment: You can also use the transformation to Hessenberg form to get a tri-diagonal matrix $T=QAQ^T$ and then test the definiteness of the $2×2$ diagonal blocks.

Comment: A quick question - am I right in thinking we can work out the LDL* decomposition directly using a variant of cholesky without extracting square roots. My other question is about stability. Solving the $L^*x$ equation is backward stable (standard result) but isn't it also forwards stable since the norm of $L^*$ is at least $1$? Feel free to post as a solution and I will award the answer.

Comment: @Mathmo I would not worry about the stability of solving a triangular linear system. Stability problems will arise in triangularizing your original system to begin with.